# Increment a variable each time a function is run

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function such that

- each time the function runs, the value of variable `P` will increase;
- the number of times the function runs is set by the variable `runtimes`.

For example:

```
var runtimes = '25';
var P = '1';

function send(){
 //some function
}
```

After the first run, variable `P` will be 2 and the second run will start.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function from a loop:

```
var runtime = 25;
var P = 1;

function send(){
    P++;
}

for (var i = 0; i < runtime; i++) {
    send();
}
```

Or keep track of the iterations in the function itself and call it once:

```
var iterations = 0;
var runtime = 25;
var P = 1;

function send(){
    P++;
    if (++iterations < runtime) {
        send();
    }
}

send();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var runtime = 25;
var P = 1;

for(var P = 1; P < runtime; send(), P++) { }

function send(){
 //some function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendMultipleTime(){
var runtime = 25;
var P = 1;

while(P<=25) 
 send();
 P++;
}

function send(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop, if I've understood the question correctly.

```
var runtime = 25;
    var P = 1;

    for (var i = P; i <= runtime; i++) {
        function send() {  
            console.log(i + ' ' + P + ' ' + runtime);
        }
        send();
        P++;
    }
```